# How to Include image in email using sails email hook

Tags: sails.js

Sails version: 0.12.14
sails-hook-email: 0.12.1

I am trying to send image in the email so that I can show in the email, and below is the code,

Note: I don't want to send it as an attachment, but want to show in the html.ejs page itself (i.e. in the email itself).

### views/emailTemplates/forgotPassword/html.ejs

```
<p>Dear <%=recipientName%>,</p>  
<br/>
<img src="/images/img1.png" width="300">
```

But it is not visible in the mail.

So how to include the images from assets/images folder to the above html.ejs file and make them visible in the mail that we send.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is available on the internet, you can do that just by giving the making the `src` attribute absolute instead of relative. Something like this:

```
<img src="http://mywebsite.com/images/img1.png" width="300">
```

If your app is just on localhost or not online, then this won't work. The only solution then is to "embed" them image, which some email clients will display as attachments.

Note that some clients may show a "blocked remote content / click to allow remote content" message before they show your image properly.